# Google Authenticator Time-Based Authorization in PHP

Tags: php, google-authentication

I need to implement Google authenticator in PHP. To achieve this I used this library: https://github.com/PHPGangsta/GoogleAuthenticator This method is based on secret token which knows both PHP application and Google authenticator in my phone. One thing I dont understand is how to store secret in databse in secure way. Cause if somebody stole the secret from db is able to generate the code which will pass the control. I think I cant store it as raw value in db. Am I right?

Answer (score 0):

You should definitely encrypt it.

In fact, you should encrypt all data that you store in your DB as it's best practice (obviously, you should be hashing passwords, rather than encrypting them), particularly with sensitive data.